# How do I display labels from data on Dissimilarity matrix using Coldiss function rather than default numbers?

Tags: r

I think I have read every page on the internet that mentions coldiss and I am still having trouble getting the labels to look correctly.  In the image I inserted, the matrices look good but the labels are default numbers (so aren't that useful for a stand alone image) and in the ordered matrix the matrix gets ordered correctly, but the labels didn't re-order, which doesn't make sense.

[Matrix output images][1]

My questions are:
1) How do I get the labels to order properly for the ordered matrix?  If the cells in the heat map are changing colors after being ordered, the respective labels should be different too.

2) Is it possible to edit the coldiss function to use my isolate labels that can be found in the top row or first  column to label the heat map rather than the default numbers?

**Here is the code I'm running.**

```
library(gclus)
library(ape)

source("coldiss.txt")

tree<-read.tree("BP_SNPS_only-BioNJ_tree_100BS")
PatristicDistMatrix100BS<-cophenetic.phylo(tree)

coldiss(D =  PatristicDistMatrix100BS, nc = 4, byrank = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
```

**Here is the coldiss.txt file:**

```
# coldiss()
# Color plots of a dissimilarity matrix, without and with ordering
#
# License: GPL-2 
# Author: Francois Gillet, 23 August 2012
#

"coldiss" <- function(D, nc = 4, byrank = TRUE, diag = FALSE)
{
require(gclus)

if (max(D)>1) D <- D/max(D)

if (byrank) {
    spe.color <- dmat.color(1-D, cm.colors(nc))
}
else {
    spe.color <- dmat.color(1-D, byrank=FALSE, cm.colors(nc))
}

spe.o <- order.single(1-D)
speo.color <- spe.color[spe.o, spe.o]

op <- par(mfrow=c(1,2), pty="s")

if (diag) {
    plotcolors(spe.color, rlabels=attributes(D)$Labels, 
        main="Dissimilarity Matrix", 
        dlabels=attributes(D)$Labels)
    plotcolors(speo.color, rlabels=attributes(D)$Labels[spe.o], 
        main="Ordered Dissimilarity Matrix", 
        dlabels=attributes(D)$Labels[spe.o])
}
else {
    plotcolors(spe.color, rlabels=attributes(D)$Labels, 
        main="Dissimilarity Matrix")
    plotcolors(speo.color, rlabels=attributes(D)$Labels[spe.o], 
        main="Ordered Dissimilarity Matrix")
}

par(op)
}

# Usage:
# coldiss(D = dissimilarity.matrix, nc = 4, byrank = TRUE, diag = FALSE)
# If D is not a dissimilarity matrix (max(D) > 1), then D is divided by     max(D)
# nc                            number of colours (classes)
# byrank= TRUE      equal-sized classes
# byrank= FALSE     equal-length intervals
# diag = TRUE           print object labels also on the diagonal

# Example:
# coldiss(spe.dj, nc=9, byrank=F, diag=T)
```

**Here is an abbreviated version of PatristicDistMatrix100BS:**
    CDC-B043_1995   CDC-A267_1994   CDC-A161_1992   CDC-C931_1998
CDC-B043_1995   0   0.00099 0.00099 0.00166
CDC-A267_1994   0.00099 0   0.00066 0.00133
CDC-A161_1992   0.00099 0.00066 0   0.00133
CDC-C931_1998   0.00166 0.00133 0.00133 0

I hope this provides all the relevant information and thank you for any help you can provide even if it's a completely different function.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the code. The main problem I think is some other packages you have loaded. I also had same problem but when I tried separately it worked well and as you require. Just remove other packages or calculate separately. For more details have a look on the code of chapter three of this document (http://adn.biol.umontreal.ca/~numericalecology/numecolR/). Here is the code I work with.

(vegan must be loaded after ade4 to avoid some conflicts)

```
library(ade4)
library(vegan)
library(gclus)
library(cluster)
library(FD)
```

files must be in the working directory. You can search this file from internet from this link (https://github.com/JoeyBernhardt/NumericalEcology)

```
source("coldiss.R")
source("panelutils.R")
```

Then calculate your dissimilarity matrix and plot using the code

```
BCD <- vegdist(df[-1])
coldiss(BCD, byrank = FALSE, diag = TRUE)
```

Hopefully it will work.